# Is it possible to skip maven-javadoc-plugin execution in an Eclipse run configuration?

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a few Maven projects in Eclipse 2019-6 that each include the maven-javadoc-plugin (v2.8) in their pom (which I don't want to modify), but in some cases I'd like to skip building the javadoc.jar when I run maven package or install through Eclipse (because for a couple of these projects, the javadoc.jar takes a fair amount of time to build).

Is there an argument I can pass through the Eclipse m2 run configuration that will allow me to skip the javadoc.jar when I run a package or install locally?

I've searched fair amount for tutorials or documentation of m2 run configurations in Eclipse and haven't found anything much more than "here's how to set up a Maven run configuration" with no extra options or advanced configurations.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding maven.javadoc.skip=true in the build parameters table of your launch configuration (equivalent to -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true in a CLI build)